# how indexing happens on a NTFS drive

Tags: indexing, ntfs, ntfs-mft

how does the computer retrive a particular entry in the MFT table for a file or directory?
I read through many documents which describe the structure of NTFS and MFT, but i fail to understand say i have a file in E:\documents\test.txt, how can i identify it's entry in the MFT index. Is it sequential?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented a readonly ntfs library ([UMFS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/umfs/)) in the distant past.

The root directory of a volume is always stored in mft record 5.  Once you can read the data stream for the directory, you can walk the b+tree (as @Christopher said) stored in the stream, finding the subdirectory or file you are interested in.

Answer (score 0):

NTFS uses B+trees internally for the file indexes.  A B+tree is a binary tree.  This [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%2B_tree) is as good an explanation as any w/r to how B+trees work.

Comment: thanks, so if i go about implementing enumerating all files and directory in a folder, there is no place i can start from? I will have to iterate through all entries? like in FAT32 where there is an entry for Root, isn't there such entry poing in MFT

Comment: NTFS uses B trees, not B+ trees.  FYI.